# Jackson Serializers Spring Beans

Tags: spring, jackson

I would like to create some serializers which are aware of some of my spring beans. The best way seems so far to me is extending DefaultSerializerProvider but I could not be sure.

```
@Component
public class PhotoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

   @Autowired
   Service service;

   @Override
   public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      jgen.writeString(service.doIt(value));
   }
}
```

What is the correct way of creating some serializers by Spring?

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10768 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson HandlerInstantiator to build a bridge between spring and jackson serializer.

It is well described here :

http://www.runningasroot.com/blog/2012/05/02/autowiring-jackson-deserializers-in-spring/